# Error at Android Support plugin on android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, illegalargumentexception

I just want to ask if there are any solution to fix the error in Android Support Library :

> Illegal Argument Exception: window with id="Preview" is already registered: window with id="Preview" is already registered

whenever i click the text editor, this pops up on my event log. And it also says there that the errors came from Android Support plugin. and i dont know what to do to it. and I am just a beginner to using android studio.

Pls help..  :)